# SilverStripe GridField: add a 'type' dropdown to the 'add' button

Tags: silverstripe

I'm currently trying to manage items of a class as well as items of subclasses together in a GridField (think of a GridField containing 'Apple' and 'Banana' items, both subclasses from 'Fruit').

I already found how to switch the class of an item using some ClassName dropdown in the detail form (as it's done in the 'Page Type' dropdown contained in the 'Settings' tab for SiteTree items), and it's working fine.

What i'd like to do now is to already choose the subclass on creation, having a dropdown containing all classes next to the 'Add' button of the GridField.
Unfortunately, the 'Add' button seems to call some 'EditForm' action in LeftAndMain, and i can't figure out where to go from here.

Does anyone know wheter this can be done extending some of GridFields' classes or the like?

Comment: This could definitely be done - you'll want to look into creating your own custom grid field component. See GridFieldAddNewButton and GridFieldDetailForm for examples. The grid field documentation also has some details.

Comment: i've already had a look into those GridField classes and the docs as well, but i don't quite get it yet. maybe someone knows a module which does something similar to what i'm after, so i could examine it's code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This functionality would be quite useful, so I've implemented it in my grid field extensions module: [the commit in question](https://github.com/ajshort/silverstripe-gridfieldextensions/commit/d7a9d470f9517b1126fc26f0b88106c324ec6273).

[Grid Field Extensions Module](https://github.com/ajshort/silverstripe-gridfieldextensions)

To get it up and running, do something like the code below. It will automatically populate a dropdown with the parent class and any subclasses, and let the user choose which type to create.

```
$config = $grid->getConfig();
$config->removeComponentsByType('GridFieldAddNewButton');
$config->addComponent(new GridFieldAddNewMultiClass());
```

Comment: awesome, thanks for that! just can't get it to work, whenever i add an item i get a blank screen saying "Action 'add-multi-class' isn't allowed on class GridField". tried adding the action to GridField::$allowed_actions but get the message "Action 'add-multi-class' isn't available on class GridField." then. is there some more configuration required?

Comment: What URL is being requested? it should be something like /add-multi-class/ClassName

Comment: the url requested is '/admin/pages/edit/EditForm/field/SimpleFormFields/add-multi-class', where 'SimpleFormFields' is the DataObject base class i want to add

Comment: didn't get round to looking at this for a while, but i just did a fresh install based on the cms/framework master branches and it's working now. thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I've just done something similar in SS 3.1, its a 2 step process, but could be modified to be a 1 step.

In your super class add a dropdown for "ClassName" in getCMSFields() eg:

```
public function getCMSFields() {
    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();
    $fields->addFieldToTab("Root.Main", 
        new DropdownField("ClassName", "Type", 
            array(
                "Apple" => "Apple", 
                "Banana" => "Banana",

            )
        )
    );

    return $fields;
}
```

Then when they click save on that page they it will show the get CMS fields for the subclass that was selected.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but when reading the second paragraph of my question you'll find that i had already implemented this type of solution before